# What Effect Could Splits or Cracks in a Cricket Bat Have?

Tags: cricket, equipment, maintenance

I am wondering how much of a different small splits/cracks in the toe of a cricket bat makes I shall add a few photos of the cracks.

The splits aren't very large, and I was wondering if they need to be repaired (I know nothing about bat repairing), or whether they won't really have that much effect? Also, of course, is there a realistic chance of the cracks' getting significantly larger and causing damage?

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]

Comment: Hi Smiley Sam! The use of Hi, Thanks etc is [not encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/187824). Also, capitalizing title [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98069/187824). That's why I updated your question.

Comment: I'm asking someone to give up some time in order to help me, so I'll be polite and say "thank you". Also, I'm rather OCD about grammar (:P), and titles should have each word capitalised, except for articles (eg, a), some prepositions (eg with, to), etc.

Comment: Actually, if your questions is good (as it is and +1 for it) people who want to answer will answer anyway even when your question doesn't have such politeness. :)

Comment: Fair enough - as in your links, different people prefer different ways of doing it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the way the crack is moving up the back of the bat it needs some form of repair or strengthening before it breaks.  Depending on where your based I'd try and find a local bat maker or contact the shop you bought it from to get Kookaburra to look at it.  I've generally found the bigger brands won't deal with you direct, you have to go via the shop.

Judging by the face you've already had this taped at the toe, it's probably worth reapplying some tape if you need to use this while you arrange a repair.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the bat is damaged, but not irrepairable, if  you have such an issue, a good fix is to sand the bottom, and put a Kevlar toe guard (or get this put on). It will simultaneously hold the toe of the bat together and stop any further moisture getting in.